# winjs list view scrolling horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, winjs

I have used a WinJS list view in my program with display style ms-flexbox .But it is scrolling horizontally beyond its width  with overflow hidden. How I can remove this scrolling and make number of items in a row as 5?

Comment: Can you be more specific and perhaps include some images of (a) what you want and (b) what you're seeing? Are you trying to prevent the ListView from panning at all, or trying to limit how it lays out items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your design as `display:-ms-grid`, and set 5th row height as `-ms-grid-rows: auto auto auto auto 1fr`.

For more info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/hh673533(v=vs.85).aspx